# Output side-by-side ediff to html

Tags: html, ediff

Vim has a command :tohtml which is particularly useful when sharing side-by-side diffs to non-programmers - they can open the resulting html file to see the results of a vimdiff.

In emacs I use ediff but once with this side-by-side comparison is there a way to write these diffs out to HTML?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Exactly how to reproduce the html file you want in vim (i.e., what does your buffer look like when typing `:TOhtml`). It would help us come up with a soluton.

Comment: This page describes the Vim feature :TOhtml when outputting diffs:  http://technogems.blogspot.com/2011/09/generate-side-by-side-diffs-in-html.html  .  Is there something similar in emacs?  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use emacs to call that one-liner vim command line?

Comment: That is a great idea.  I'll try that.